# Get post content until read more Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

I want to get content of a post until the read more that I set when I'm creating a new post, so far I'm able to get the content doing

```
apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

I would like to get only until the Read More, I'm integrating a blog to the home page and I only need a brief description of the article.

Thanks

Comment: ...and you'd like us to code it for you or help you with a problem you're having?

Comment: no, I just want to know if this is possible and if it is what function do i have to use

Answer (score 1):

This is a function in the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) that does that, hope it helps.

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content('Read more');
print $content;
?>
```